# Magento 2 : get "Catalog Input Type for Store Owner" value

Tags: magento2, attributes

I create an attribute like this 
[image]

how to check in list.phtml

```
if(attribute == "yes"){
show block
}else{
don\'t show any thing
}
```

**Update:**
I get it like this:

```
$_product->getAttributeText("stock_display");
```

but it always returns "no" Although I have set some product "yes"
[image]

Any help? Thank in advance.

Comment: what is the code of your attribute ?

Comment: what do you mean? please explain

Comment: I update answer

Comment: if you check value of `$_product->getAttributeText("stock_display");` it will return 0 or 1

Comment: you need to check 0 or 1 in your condition

Comment: did you get the value of attribute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$_product->getStockDisplay();

<?php $attr = $_product->getStockDisplay(); ?>
               OR
<?php $attr = $_product->getData('stock_display'); ?>
               OR
<?php $attr = $_product->getAttributeText('stock_display'); ?>

if($attr == 1){
show block
}else{
don\'t show any thing
}
```

Comment: It works, Thank you.

Comment: glad to know :) and welcome..

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below condition

```
if($_product->getResource()->getAttribute('stock_display')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)){
    //Display Block code here
}else{
    //Don't show anything
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: it not working. still always return "no"